# How can I find out API name of Process Builder decision/actions? (myDecision, myWait, myAction)

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, error, debug

I get emails when an error is occurred from a Process Builder or Flow, such as below:

```
DECISION: myDecision4
Outcome executed: myRule_5
```

However, its very hard to debug because the API names does not give any hint.  They are all like,

**myRule, myWait, myDecision, myAction**...

how can I figure out what decision, immediate action or scheduled action they are referring to?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currently the only way to figure out the details of those `mySomething` is to examine the process builder metadata (metadata file can be retrieved by using Salesforce CLI, ant Migration Tool, etc).

After retrieving the metadata from Salesforce, open up the `*.flow` with text editor, and you can see which `mySomething` corresponds to which decision node, action, rule, etc.

For example, I have this process builder:
[image]

The flow metadata file content is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <decisions>
        ...
        <rules>
            <name>myRule_1</name>
            <conditionLogic>and</conditionLogic>
            <conditions>
                <leftValueReference>formula_myRule_1</leftValueReference>
                <operator>EqualTo</operator>
                <rightValue>
                    <booleanValue>true</booleanValue>
                </rightValue>
            </conditions>
            <connector>
                <targetReference>myRule_1_A1</targetReference>
            </connector>
            <label>Account Rating Hot?</label>
        </rules>
    </decisions>
    ...
</Flow>
```

Salesforce automatically names my decision node as `myRule_1`, and a bit further down, the label tag will tell me that the corresponding decision node is the one I labelled as `Account Rating Hot?`.

Right above the decision node label, I can see the connector tag has `myRule_1_A1` target reference, and below is the related xml snippet:

```xml
    <actionCalls>
        ...
        <name>myRule_1_A1</name>
        <label>Post Chatter</label>
        <actionName>chatterPost</actionName>
        <actionType>chatterPost</actionType>
        ...
        </inputParameters>
    </actionCalls>
```

From the label, I can easily tell that `myRule_1_A1` is the chatter post action.

So basically in short: pull the metadata, search for the variable name, and check the corresponding label.

Comment: Thanks!! it works perfectly for me